# How do I override a class when it has a attached class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a `list-group` with some elements in it. The normal elements have `list-group-item` but   I want some elements to act as a header, so I gave it the `list-header` class.

Now my only struggle it to style it correctly.

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-header">Tags</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">Services</a>
```

I only want to change the `background-color` on the `list-group-item` when the `list-header` class is attached to it.

Something like:

```
.list-group>a.list-group-item:hover .list-header {
   background-color: #ededed;
}
```

But I guess it's not working that way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
.list-group > a.list-group-item.list-header:hover {
    background-color: #ededed;
}
```

The above will be applied when you hover over elements that have both the classes `list-group-item` and `list-header`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
.list-group>a.list-group-item.list-header:hover  {
   background-color: #ededed;
}
```

This is because both the `list-group-item` and the `list-header` classes belong to the same element.

The below sets the background to an element with `class='list-header'` when the `a` (anchor) element with `class='list-group-item` is hovered.

```
.list-group>a.list-group-item:hover .list-header {
   background-color: #ededed;
}
```